# Trigger inserting value based on values from antoher table

Tags: sql, triggers, insert

I'm new to creating database trigger and i'm having trouble getting my second trigger to work.

When a new record is inserted in table workflow, the worker need to be adjusted based on the city in the table client.

Client number is the value which is the relation between the two tables.

This is what I wrote so far:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER automatic_workflow
BEFORE INSERT ON workflow
for each row 
when(new.subject='Account' and new.fase=1)
BEGIN
if
(:new.number=client.number) and client.city='Amsterdam' then new.worker ='Bill';
end if;
END;
```

Comment: You need to `SELECT` data from `client` table.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Explain what logic you are using.  Your code doesn't make sense.

Comment: Triggers are **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: I have tried but i can't get de syntax right when using :new.number

Comment: it's oracle i'm using

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a delimiter at the start like this:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER automatic_workflow
BEFORE INSERT ON workflow
for each row 
when(new.subject='Account' and new.fase=1)
BEGIN
if
(:new.number=client.number) and client.city='Amsterdam' then new.worker ='Bill';
end if;
END;
//
```

Answer (score 0):

What is `client`?  It is not defined in the trigger.

I suspect you might want:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER automatic_workflow
BEFORE INSERT ON workflow
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (new.subject = 'Account' and new.fase = 1)
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM client c
               WHERE c.number = :new.number and    
                     c.city = 'Amsterdam' 
              ) THEN
        new.worker = 'Bill';
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: After using declare for the number from client i got the trigger working